# Azure Platform Ready - HTTPS test case failure

Tags: azure

I am trying to get my Azure application through the Microsoft Platform Ready test. I have successfully got the test up and running, but it fails on just one of the test cases. This is the output:

```
======================================================================
Log generated by Microsoft Platform Ready Test Tool - Version 2.0.0.0 
======================================================================
    Test name: MyTest v4
    Test date: 05/17/2012 08:37:45
    Tested on: Physical Machine
    Test for: Microsoft Windows Azure
======================================================================
Test case/Verification: TC 16 - If the application has HTTPS URL then is it using 
port 443 for SSL configuration?
======================================================================
SSL not configured for the application.
Test Status: Fail
======================================================================
Test case/Verification: TC 16 - If the application has HTTPS URL then is it using 
port 443 for SSL configuration?
05/17/2012 08:37:46 End of Log.
======================================================================
```

The service has one web role (two instances, to pass the resiliency test, TC 10), and there are two endpoints:

- 80 : http : redirects to the https endpoint using IIS rewrite module.
- 443 : https : delivers the site

(I also have RDP enabled, which is opening port 3389.)

In the MPR setup, I am giving the public key of the SSL cert, downloaded through a web browser, as the 'Service Certificate File'. I'm pretty sure that is the right thing to do(?).

[image: MPR Azure setup]

I have run the MPR Tool against the https endpoint 'Application URL', and it still returns failed for test case 16 - I have no idea why. Can anyone help?

Comment: The test is looking for a HTTPS to be on port 443 as per the output of the test tool in your question you state "... there are two endpoints:

80 : http : redirects to the https endpoint using IIS rewrite module.
43 : https : delivers the site"
Should https not be on port 443 and not 43?
I know nothing of Azure, so this may be fine, but it caught my eye so I thought it may be worth mentioning

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo - I am on port 443.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that MPR tool which is available to download is outdated and by some reason when someone download this tool they get old outdated tool, due to CDN cache or something, I am really surprised why it is keep happening.

What you do is please directly contact MPR Support team at mprsupport@microsoft.com and they will provide you a link to download the newer MPR tool which will not show this problem.

I am going to blog about this issue now as it is still causing problem to users and thats bad.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this very same problem about two months ago. Contact the MPR support team and they will help you resolve the issue! This is the only way, as there appear to be a bug in the MPR tool in the part for the SSL verification.